# Disable Kerberos password

Tags: linux, debian, kerberos

When trying to add a new user on a Debian 6.0 box I get:

```
passwd: User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

How can I disable Kerberos authentication and use the good old UNIX password?

Comment: How was it initially set up? Sounds like your PAM configuration is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes PAM seems to be messed up, this is a VPS server. I upgraded it with apt from lenny to squeeze I think that maybe screwed something. Not sure how to disable/remove PAM or fix it. I have never touched PAM before so it got the default settings.

Answer (score 6):

you just have to:
aptitude purge libpam-krb5
this package seems to be automatically installed while upgrading and after that it thinks you're running kerberos authentication... at least on my VPS.

Comment: Upgraded from Debian 5 to 6 and had this issue.